# ¿Cómo enviar una lista de elementos en un correo con sails hook email?

Tags: nodejs, email, sailsjs

Estoy tratando de enviar una lista de elementos como parte de un correo utilizando [sails hook email](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-email), actualmente en mi controlador estoy procesando la lista para generar un archivo html y pasarlo como parámetro:

```
send_email:function (req,res) {
    let html="";
      for(let i=0;i<req.alertas.length;i++){
        html+="<section id='1' class='alert-element border-bottom' data-title='1' style='min-height: 100px;max-height: 100px;padding: 15px 20px 10px 50px;border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(200, 200, 200, .5);margin-bottom: 10px;'>" +
        "          <span class='title-alert' style='font-size: 16pt;color: rgb(50,50,50)'>"+req.alertas[i].titulo+"</span>" +
        "          <p class='alert-description'></p>" +
        "          <div class='alert-indicators' style='font-style: italic;color: rgb(100,100,100);font-size: 8pt; display: inline-block;'>" +
        "            <div class='col-70 alert-time'>" +
        "              <strong>Inicio: </strong><span>16/05/2018</span> <strong>último: </strong><span>16/05/2018</span>" +
        "            </div>" +
        "            <div class='col-30'>" +
        "              <span><span id='n1'>5</span> registros</span>" +
        "            </div>" +
        "          </div>" +
        "          <span class='label label-warning' style='padding: 3px 5px;font-size: 7pt;background-color: rgb(197,64,64);border-radius: 10px;float: right;color: white;font-weight: bold;'>Warning</span>" +
        "        </section>";
    }

    sails.hooks.email.send(
      req.email_template,
      {
        alertas: req.alertas,
        resumen: req.resumen,
        html:html
      },
      {
        to: req.correo_electronico,
        subject: req.asunto
      },
      function(err) {console.log(err || "It worked!");}
    );
  }
```

En la plantilla de email solo coloco la variable html de este modo:

```
<%=html%>
```

Pero me está dando como resultado algo como esto:[image: Correo recibido]
Existe algún modo de darle formato al parámetro para que la plantilla lo vea como etiquetas html o quizá poder ejecutar un bucle en la plantilla de correo??

pdta:intenté adjuntar un script y adjuntar el contenido por medio de la función html de javascript, pero gmail bloquea cualquier script en la plantilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede agregar bucles dentro del template del email:

```
<% _.each(alertas, function (alerta) { %>
  <section>..elemento html a repetirse..</section>
<% }) %>
```